# Python - unable to get simple while loop to work (student project)

Tags: python, while-loop

I hope someone can help me with a school project.

The question is -

*A university wants a print-out of how many students failed the first year mathematics final examination. Each record contains the student’s number, name, mathematics score and maximum score possible. Each student must have a report printed with his or her number, name, percentage and a remark stating whether a pass or fail is achieved (50% and above is a pass). Processing continues until a student number of 0 is entered. Count how many students failed, as well as the total number of students, and print these totals*

I am trying to get the student number from user input to either loop or break out of the loop but I can't get it to work.

I've changed my code so many times but this is my last attempt -

```
total_students = 0
total_fail = 0

  while True:
  student_number = int(input("what is your student number? "))
  name = input("What is your name?")
  math_score = int(input("Math score?"))
  max_score = int(input("Max score? "))

  if student_number == 0:
      print(total_fail)
      print(total_students)

  if math_score / max_score * 100 >= 50:
        print("You passed")
        total_students += 1

  elif math_score / max_score * 100 < 50:
     print("You failed")
     total_fail += 1
     total_students += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  How are you trying to break out the loop?

Comment: `while True` is an infinite loop and you need to break out of it to continue executing the other code statements.

Comment: Hello! I am trying to break out of the loop when the user enters 0 as a student number. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: You need to add your condition somewhere within the loop. Right now, the loop will keep repeating infinitely and won't go to your if condition.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/)

Comment: Thank you! I will quickly work through that!

Answer (score 2):

The indentation for while loop is incorrect, and since you want the program to stop after student number is 0, youll have to use break. For more info on it check  [this out.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue)

```
total_students = 0
total_fail = 0
while True:
  student_number = int(input("what is your student number? "))
  name = input("What is your name?")
  math_score = int(input("Math score?"))
  max_score = int(input("Max score? "))

  if student_number == 0:
      print(total_fail)
      print(total_students)
      break

  if math_score / max_score * 100 >= 50:
        print("You passed")
        total_students += 1

  elif math_score / max_score * 100 < 50:
     print("You failed")
     total_fail += 1
     total_students += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

1- the while loop is infinite so you need to put **break** to end the loop when needed

2- your codes should be inside the `while loop`

notice :

```
while True:
    #code inside the loop
```